# Are "top" and "to top" the same direction for linear gradients?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Browser implementations of `linear-gradient()` have evolved to support both `top` and `to top` as anchor values.  Are they the same direction or opposites?

Answer (score 4):

They are **opposites**.  `to top` uses the first color argument at the bottom of the element, while `top` uses the first color argument at the top.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LtFsB/1/).  MDN has the [full details and history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Specifications).

Comment: You should add the rest of the prefixes to your fiddle.

Comment: @BoltClock you caught me.  Hoping I could slip that one through.  There's a good variety in there now.  Wasn't compelled to add the older webkit and ie incantations.

Comment: Haha sorry, you'll want to avoid running into me then - I'm pretty picky about that sort of thing. I upvoted your answer because it's correct, but I added my own to expand on the topic.

Answer (score 4):

They are *not* the same direction; they are opposites.

`to top` is an abbreviation for "bottom to top", whereas `top` means "start from the top".<sup>1</sup> This is true not only for the other sides, but also for corners such as `top right` and `bottom left`.

Both directional keyword syntaxes were documented in the CSS Images level 3 module, which is why so many implementations made use of the legacy syntax early on. The last public working draft that made use of the legacy syntax is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110712/#linear-gradients); you can see a note acknowledging the sheer ambiguity around it, which eventually led to the use of the keyword `to` in subsequent revisions. The latest revision is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients).

[Some browsers support both syntaxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Browser_compatibility) for indicating the direction of a linear gradient in their vendor-specific `-*-linear-gradient()` functions, however it should be noted that the standardized function `linear-gradient()` only accepts the new syntax with the `to` keyword. (If a browser accepts both syntaxes in the unprefixed function then it's either outdated or in violation of the spec, and should be reported.)

Note also that the default direction is `top` for the legacy syntax and `to bottom` for the current syntax. This means that the default direction is the same, and is unchanged.

Also worth mentioning is that if you use [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/), [it already accounts for this change](http://lea.verou.me/2012/07/important-prefix-free-update), with the minor caveat that you need to include both syntaxes in separate declarations:

> If you include both versions, the cascade does its job and ignores the latter version if it’s not supported:
>
> ```
> background: linear-gradient(top, white, black);
> background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
> ```

Both statements will be prefixed only in browsers that require the prefix, but regardless of that the browser will use the cascade to figure out which one it can use.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>If there were a `from` keyword, then `top` and `from top` would be equivalent.</sub>