# How to make background-image with linear-gradient work on IE 11?

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients, internet-explorer-11

Any idea how I can make `background-image` with `linear-gradient` to work on IE 11?

The following code works fine on IE 10 but doesn't work on IE 11.

```
background-image: url(IMAGE), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #BEE38F);
```

I can make `linear-gradient` to work on IE 6-9, 11 using the following `filter` but background image is not displayed in this case.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#BEE38F',GradientType=0 )
```

I'm open to an ideas.

**Update:** Here's the code I currently have.

```
background-image: url(IMAGE), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#BEE38F));
background-image: url(IMAGE), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #BEE38F);
background-image: url(IMAGE), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #BEE38F);
background-image: url(IMAGE), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #BEE38F);
background-image: url(IMAGE), -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #BEE38F);
background-image: url(IMAGE), linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #BEE38F);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#BEE38F',GradientType=0 );
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle, or online example we can look at? IE11 supports linear-gradient unprefixed ([See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj152126(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`linear-gradient()` is supported unprefixed on IE10 RTM and later, including IE11. You never need the `-ms-` prefix — only the pre-release versions of IE10 required it and [those versions don't even run anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340761/ms-animation-should-i-include-this-for-older-browsers/42341302#42341302). You're just wasting space by including the prefix in your CSS.

Note that the directional syntax for `linear-gradient()` is different; what was originally `top` is now represented as `to bottom` instead (see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/25/unprefixed-css3-gradients-in-ie10.aspx), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486680/are-top-and-to-top-the-same-direction-for-linear-gradients), and the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients) for details):

```
background-image: url(IMAGE), linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #BEE38F);
```

Comment: If you still have that `filter`, remove it. Or at least hide it behind a conditional comment. Or, if you must support IE9, then you cannot use CSS gradients *or* IE filters - you will need to fall back to an SVG or worst case scenario a normal image.

Comment: I removed 'filter' as you suggested but it still doesn't work for me :(

Comment: NOTE : I realized that in order to work in IE11, the unprefixed `linear-gradient()` must be the first declaration in the CSS rule followed by the -webkit-, -moz-, -o- and -ms-.

Comment: I'm not seeing the same issues. If you have the filter listed first, background-image properties can seemingly be listed in any order in IE11 (as long as the w3c version is listed last). I'm testing with 11.0.9600.16521 and have not noticed any significant issues. IE11 seems to be more strict in conforming to the w3 spec than chrome or firefox, considering both mentioned still accept top instead of the spec's to bottom. As long as you have the property stated like @BoltClock has given in their answer - it works regardless of whatever else is present.

Answer (score 11):

Maddening, isn't it?

**Prior to IE 11**,

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#cccccc');
```

**For IE 11:**

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
```

That's right folks, we not only have to worry about supporting older IEs, apparently we'll now have to deal with NEWER IE quirks as well...

Comment: `background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF,#CCCCCC);` works fine with filters present.
Also, if you were trying to target IE9's SVG support, a simple filter wasn't all we had to do prior to IE 11 anyhow.

Comment: -ms prefix is not needed. Instead **top** use **to bottom**

Answer (score 3):

These are all super great solutions **if** you are overlaying a linear gradient directly on text. But if you want to display it overtop an image it doesn't work in IE.. don't ask me why but it doesn't.

I scowered many resources and finally came across this [diddy](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/fallback-for-css-blending-modes)

```
@media (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
 .yourTargetClass:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-221deg, rgba(205,234,255,0.41), rgba(227,253,255,0.82)); /* THIS IS WHAT EVER OVERLAY COLOUR YOU WANT */ }
    opacity:0.55;
  }
}
```

I wrapped this within an IE selector for 10+. You need to include the opacity as that will help blend the gradient overlay with the content.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that for IE 11 the liniear-gradient works fine on itself. Unfortunately it doesn't work well as an overlay if you want to use a bacground image as well.

The only way that I was able to make it work for me was to switch to using rgba instead of hex colors and percentage. Also it only worked when I put the liniear-gradient first and not vice versa.

```
background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.52), rgba(117, 19, 93, 0.73)),
    url('images/background.jpg');
```

Comment: dude you are awesome...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and in addition to doing the filter and linear-gradient, I also had to add the **width** in my CSS class, once I set the width, I could see my custom styles with background gradient.