# CSS Gradient not working properly in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

The issue is that the CSS gradient I am using as part of the background is repeating after every 120 pixels instead of taking up the whole page length. After careful experimentation, I believe that I have figured out that the issue is that Internet Explorer 11 thinks that the page length is only 120px. I am not getting this problem with Edge, Firefox or Chrome (though I was told that Chrome does have the same problem but the CSS is coded in such a way that it is ignoring the perceived page height).

Is there a way I can modify the CSS to tell Internet Explorer that the page length is not 120px?

Relevant data:

The existing code relating to the gradient is:

```
body{background: #fdb6b4; /* Old browsers */ 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffdadd 0%, #fdb6b4 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */ 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffdadd), color-stop(100%,#fdb6b4)); /* Chrome4-9,Safari4-5 */ 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffdadd 0%,#fdb6b4 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */ 
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffdadd 0%,#fdb6b4 100%); /* Opera 11.10-11.50 */ 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffdadd 0%,#fdb6b4 100%); /* IE10 preview */ 
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffdadd 0%,#fdb6b4 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */ 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffdadd', endColorstr='#fdb6b4',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */}
```

Link to the blog in question to see exactly what the issue is:
http://www.http://madinskincareland.com

above: how IE11 renders, below: how Firefox 51.0.1 renders (all other tested browsers including available mobile devices render properly)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make background-image with linear-gradient work on IE 11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980079/how-to-make-background-image-with-linear-gradient-work-on-ie-11)

Comment: Try this http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: I got the code for it from colorzilla

Comment: And the code does work, but on IE11 it is restricted to a height of 120px instead of, as on other browsers including Edge, the full height of the page.

Answer (score 0):

According to CSS/linear-gradient documentation, you need to use background-image.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

```
body{
  background-color: #fdb6b4; /* Old browsers */ 
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffdadd 0%, #fdb6b4 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */ 
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffdadd), color-stop(100%,#fdb6b4)); /* Chrome4-9,Safari4-5 */ 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffdadd 0%,#fdb6b4 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */ 
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffdadd 0%,#fdb6b4 100%); /* Opera 11.10-11.50 */ 
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffdadd 0%,#fdb6b4 100%); /* IE10 preview */ 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffdadd 0%,#fdb6b4 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */ 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffdadd', endColorstr='#fdb6b4',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Comment: Just made the suggested edits, Milo, and there is no change.

Comment: In fact, it made it worse by getting rid of the mint background of the sections.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with applying the gradient to the body tag. What I do is add another tag (e.g. Main or section) inside of the body, position it relative top 0, left 0, and then apply the gradient to that element. I hope this helps!