# Are browser prefixes required for all version of animation keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations, vendor-prefix

If a designer is using a fancy css animation and hopes to have functionality in older and newer browsers, we usually create a @keyframes and a @-webkit-keyframes section.  Most of the examples I have seen use both non-prefixed and browser prefixed css under both keyframes, but is this necessary.

```
@keyframes coolEffect {
  -webkit-transform: some value;
  transform: some value;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: some value;
  animation-timing-function: some value;
}
@-webkit-keyframes coolEffect {
  -webkit-transform: some value;
  transform: some value;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: some value;
  animation-timing-function: some value;
}
```

Do we need non-prefixed values in the @-webkit-keyframes, since a browser using that would also use -webkit- prefixed css?  And likewise since we are using @-webkit-keyframes, do we need to include -webkit- prefixed css in the main @keyframes?  Would a simpler smaller version work equally as well?

```
@keyframes coolEffect {
  transform: some value;
  animation-timing-function: some value;
}
@-webkit-keyframes coolEffect {
  -webkit-transform: some value;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: some value;
}
```

To clarify, I am not asking about what would work for my particular website, I am asking about functionality and whether or not code sample two would work the same as code sample one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545533/how-should-you-prefix-transform-properties-in-css3-animations/28546443#28546443):

> - WebKit-based browsers (including Opera 15 and later) still require the `-webkit-` prefix for animations today, and transforms are only unprefixed in recent versions of Chrome. You will need the prefix for both features.

(Transforms were unprefixed in Chrome 36; animations were not unprefixed until Chrome 43. Both features were [unprefixed simultaneously in Safari 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW35) so you never need to worry about prefixed/unprefixed overlap in Safari.)

In a nutshell, while your two samples don't provide exactly the same functionality, there is no point including any unprefixed properties in `@-webkit-keyframes` as most WebKit browsers that depend on the prefixed at-rule are never going to need the unprefixed properties. Specifically, from [our chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/181826):

> You can lose the unprefixed [animation-timing-function] declaration. @keyframes is in the same family as the animation-* properties and no browser in existence supports one unprefixed without the other
>
> As for transforms, only a very fringe few browsers simultaneously support unprefixed transforms and require prefixes on animations. These browsers do still support prefixed transforms, so similarly you can lose unprefixed transforms in @-webkit-keyframes
>
> Note the difference between "support" and "require"

So, code sample two is all you need. It's **over 40% smaller** than code sample one, with **no** loss of functionality. 40% is a *big* deal. The only change I'd make is move the `@-webkit-keyframes` rule up:

```
@-webkit-keyframes coolEffect {
  -webkit-transform: some value;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: some value;
}
@keyframes coolEffect {
  transform: some value;
  animation-timing-function: some value;
}
```

Readers may also be interested in my comments on Autoprefixer:

> I assume Autoprefixer sees that Chrome 36-42 supports unprefixed transforms but requires prefixed animations, so it puts transform in @-webkit-keyframes. I don't think that's a good approach. It needlessly doubles the transform declarations. All those versions of Chrome still understand -webkit-transform, so might as well stick to just that
>
> Autoprefixer is good for those who just don't want to have to worry about prefixes or doing all the research needed to really optimize their stylesheets
>
> If you want to optimize your stylesheet, you'll need to do quite a bit of research to find out where prefixes are needed and where they aren't, where unprefixed declarations are needed and where you can leave them out, etc. Prefixes are a pain either way ;)

Comment: Thanks. The @-webkit-keyframes rule actually does come first in the wesbite's code, I just typed the sample in reverse :(

Answer (score 1):

No. All modern browsers, even going back to IE10, support unprefixed animations.
([source](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation))

Comment: Most notably, Internet Explorer has never required a prefix for animations, although it does support prefixed animations anyway. The only builds that require the prefix are prerelease builds of IE10, and those don't run anymore anyway. Also see the footnotes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340761/ms-animation-should-i-include-this-for-older-browsers/42341302#42341302).

Comment: Is Yandex exception?