# Linear gradient with stops does not work in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, linear-gradients

I try to get this background work in IE11. I can't see the fault… does anybody know what is wrong with this?

```
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, red 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 60px 30px;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/201gyf6L/

Thanks

–––– UPDATE ––––

I found a work around for IE11.

```
background: linear-gradient(left, red 1px, transparent 1.1px), linear-gradient(top, red 1px, transparent 1.1px);
```

I updated "to right" to "left" and "to bottom" to "top" and, important, wrote 1.1px instead of 1px. Kinda ugly, but works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make background-image with linear-gradient work on IE 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980079/how-to-make-background-image-with-linear-gradient-work-on-ie-11)

Comment: I'd recommend you to use a gradient generator and you'll get a lot of code for other browsers too http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Even don't work with -ms- prefix :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
       div {
           width: 420px;
           height: 720px;
           background-color: white;
           background-image: linear-gradient(red 2px, transparent 2px), 
               linear-gradient(90deg, red 2px, transparent 2px), 
               linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3) 1px, transparent 1px), 
               linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 1px, transparent 1px);
           background-size: 60px 30px;
       }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The output as below (using IE 11.1.17134.0 version):

[image]

Comment: Okay, this is interesting. I tried this with 2px and it worked. But with 1px it does not. Sadly, I need it with 1px.


`background: linear-gradient(red 2px, transparent 2px), linear-gradient(90deg, red 2px, transparent 2px);
background-size: 60px 30px;`