# Value Error : background-image bottom is not a color value )

Tags: css

Can Some one can Help me to Rectify this Issue., I am Getting The Error as :Value Error : background-image bottom is not a color value )

```
.btn {
    padding:5px 10px; border-radius:5px; color:#FFF; text-shadow: 1px 1px #333;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #94bee0; border: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(42,112,166) 21%, rgb(66,136,190) 61%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(42,112,166) 21%, rgb(66,136,190) 61%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(42,112,166) 21%, rgb(66,136,190) 61%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(42,112,166) 21%, rgb(66,136,190) 61%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(42,112,166) 21%, rgb(66,136,190) 61%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.21, rgb(42,112,166)),
        color-stop(0.61, rgb(66,136,190))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your unprefixed `linear-gradient()` syntax needs to be updated to match [the latest spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients), which has a different syntax for specifying the direction:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(42,112,166) 21%, rgb(66,136,190) 61%);
```

Note that `to top` does in fact replace `bottom`, even though it's the opposite direction. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486680/are-top-and-to-top-the-same-direction-for-linear-gradients/19488034#19488034) for an explanation.

As for the prefixed values, don't worry about them: they are non-standard and therefore cannot be validated.

Comment: Thank You., Mr., Bolt Clock