# Multiple background colors across different browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In my banner I've got a gradient. Below is the support for Chrome, Firefox & IE. However, IE 9 does not support gradients in the `ms-linear-gradient` fashion. Is it possible to make the banner a solid color for visitors on IE 9? Currently the background is white when I visit it on IE 9.

```
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#7AAC41, #16590f);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#7AAC41, #16590f);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(#7AAC41, #16590f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply add a "default" background before you gradient tags, like so:

```
background: #7AAC41
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#7AAC41, #16590f);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#7AAC41, #16590f);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#7AAC41, #16590f);
```

When the page is rendered in IE, the browser won't be able to understand the `-moz-linear-gradient`, `-webkit-linear-gradient`, and `-ms-linear-gradient` properties but will understand the `background` property. Likewise, in other browsers, the last property the browser understands will be the color.

This is known as [writing a browser fallback](http://modernweb.com/2013/07/08/using-css-fallback-properties-for-better-cross-browser-compatibility/).

Comment: @VegaStudios: In addition to this answer, you should also remove the `-ms-` prefix as it is no longer in use by any version of IE. Note that it may generate a different gradient however as the unprefixed syntax is somewhat different from the prefixed syntax. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486680/are-top-and-to-top-the-same-direction-for-linear-gradients

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a CSS conditional comment:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<![endif]-->
```

You could add a CSS file specifically for IE9, and as long as it is below the CSS file specifying the background color of the banner, it will take precedence.

Comment: I think this will method will work, but might add some bloat in terms of page size. I try to avoid conditional selectors because they are hard to manage and keep organized. Good answer, though.

Comment: Thanks, Charlie, but James is right wrt bloating page size. I went ahead and added a `background`....a duh!